# EF Core - Self-referencing Many to Many relationship

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-core, self-referencing-table

Entity model:

```
public class DocumentType : CodeBase
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan? Productiontime { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeliverable { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DocumentTypeRetractRelation> DocumentTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentTypeRetractRelation> RetractDocumentTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Relation model:

```
/// <summary>
/// Relationship between document types showing which documenttypes can 
/// retracted when delivering a new document.
/// </summary>
[Table("DocumentTypeRetractRelation")]
public class DocumentTypeRetractRelation
{
    public int DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }

    public int RetractDocumentTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentType RetractDocumentType { get; set; }
}
```

Model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentTypeRetractRelation>().HasKey(x => new { x.DocumentTypeId, x.RetractDocumentTypeId });

modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentTypeRetractRelation>()
    .HasOne(x => x.DocumentType)
    .WithMany(x => x.DocumentTypes)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.DocumentTypeId);

modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentTypeRetractRelation>()
    .HasOne(x => x.RetractDocumentType)
    .WithMany(x => x.RetractDocumentTypes)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.RetractDocumentTypeId);
```

Update writer:

```
    public async Task<DocumentType> UpdateAsync(DocumentTypeUpdateDto documentTypeUpdateDto)
    {
        using (IUnitOfWork uow = UowProvider.CreateUnitOfWork<EntityContext>())
        {
            var documentTypeRepo = uow.GetCustomRepository<IDocumentTypeRepository>();

            var existingDocument = await documentTypeRepo.GetAsync(documentTypeUpdateDto.Id);

            if (existingDocument == null)
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("DocumentType", existingDocument.Id);

            foreach (var retractDocumentTypeId in documentTypeUpdateDto.RetractDocumentTypeIds)
            {
                existingDocument.RetractDocumentTypes.Add(new DocumentTypeRetractRelation()
                {
                    DocumentTypeId = existingDocument.Id,
                    RetractDocumentTypeId = retractDocumentTypeId
                });
            }

            documentTypeRepo.Update(existingDocument);

            await uow.SaveChangesAsync();

            return existingDocument;
        }
    }
```

When trying to update the existingDocument I get the following error:

> The instance of entity type 'DocumentTypeRetractRelation' cannot be
>   tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is
>   already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a
>   unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if
>   the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you
>   are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not
>   collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other
>   new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

Comment: The exception indicates duplicate `DocumentTypeRetractRelation` **keys**. Check if the `existingDocument` navigation properties are populated. Also the lifetime of the `DbContext` used.

Comment: They are. After the savechanges the id's get replaced by 2 times the same entity which is not the case before the savechanges.

Comment: You'd probably need to load them in advance, then merge with changes instead of blindly adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the self referencing, but applying the many-to-many collection modifications which generate different `DocumentTypeRetractRelation` objects with the same PK as stated in the exception message.

The correct way currently in EF Core is to make sure `RetractDocumentTypes` of the `existingDocument` are loaded (contains the original values), then merge the changes by either using an existing or create new `DocumentTypeRetractRelation` objects.

Replace the following code

```
foreach (var retractDocumentTypeId in documentTypeUpdateDto.RetractDocumentTypeIds)
{
    existingDocument.RetractDocumentTypes.Add(new DocumentTypeRetractRelation()
    {
        DocumentTypeId = existingDocument.Id,
        RetractDocumentTypeId = retractDocumentTypeId
    });
}
```

with

```
// existingDocument.RetractDocumentTypes should be loaded (either eager or explicit)
existingDocument.RetractDocumentTypes = (
    from retractDocumentTypeId in documentTypeUpdateDto.RetractDocumentTypeIds
    join existingRelation in existingDocument.RetractDocumentTypes
    on retractDocumentTypeId equals existingRelation.RetractDocumentTypeId
    into existingRelations
    select existingRelations.FirstOrDefault() ?? new DocumentTypeRetractRelation()
    {
        DocumentTypeId = existingDocument.Id,
        RetractDocumentTypeId = retractDocumentTypeId
    }).ToList();
```

This would handle both added, removed and unchanged relations. You can do similar to `DocumentTypes`.

Actually looking at your model, the above code should be for `DocumentTypes` collection (since you a receiving the `RetractDocumentTypeIds`, which in combination with the document `Id` form the `DocumentTypes` collection content). So simply replace the `RetractDocumentTypes` with `DocumentTypes`.